# Instantiate NSDictionary. Cast an array?

Tags: ios, casting, nsdictionary

How to understand this notation of the first line? I am confused about this way of instantiating NSDictionary (lack of experience). Is this some kind of casting? It's from iOS TableViewController tutorial, cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"mainTitleKey"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"secondaryTitleKey"];
```

I would expect the following instead, it works:

```
NSDictionary *item = [arrayContainingDictionaries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"mainTitleKey"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"secondaryTitleKey"];
```

Comment: the bottom one is preferred, the top one is usually used when your getting a object out ouf a collection object and don't want to create a instance variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches should work, casting the object to NSDictionary might be just an additional measure to avoid errors, but I guess since Objective-C would send an objectForKey: message to whatever object it extracted of the NSArray it should work.

Hope this can give you some insight.